# I have to access indexes of list members in python. I want to print position of index. But in my code I am not able to check it in if conditon

Tags: python-3.x

```py
s='hello'
new=list(s)
for i in new:
    if new[i]%2==0:

        print(i)
    else:
        print(i)
```

Here `new[i]` doesn't return the index and the code gives an error. How  do I access the list index?

Comment: what does it return instead?  What error does it display, if any?  What debugging have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to access the index:

```
s='hello'
new=list(s)
for index, value in enumerate(new):
    if value == 'e':  # This looks for 'e' in the list and return index 1
        print(index)
```

Output:

```
 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the built in function enumerate(). The link to the documentation is below:

[EnumerateLink](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

The code I would use for this problem is the following :

```
s='hello'
new=list(s)
for index, value in enumerate(new):
    print(index) # or print (index,value) to see both the index and values in
```